# java - avoid unnessary thread wake-ups

Tags: multithreading, notifications, throughput, java1.4

I have a set of 12 threads executing work (*Runnable*) in parallel. In essence, each thread does the following:

```
Runnable r;

while (true) {
    synchronized (work) {
        while (work.isEmpty()) {
            work.wait();
        }
        r = work.removeFirst();
    }
    r.execute();
}
```

Work is added as following:

```
Runnable r = ...;

synchronized (work) {
    work.add(r);
    work.notify();
}
```

When new work is available, it is added to the list and the lock is notified. If there is a thread waiting, it is woken up, so it can execute this work.

Here lies the problem. When a thread is woken up, it is very likely that **another** thread will execute this work. This happens when the latter thread is done with its previous work and re-enters the *while(true)*-loop. The smaller/shorter the work actions, the more likely this will happen.

**This means I am waking up a thread for nothing.** As I need high throughput, I believe this behavior will lower the performance.

How would you solve this? In theory, I need a mechanism which allows me to cancel a pending thread wake-up notification. Of course, this is not possible in Java.

I thought about introducing a work list for each thread. Instead of pushing the work into one single list, the work is spread over the 12 work lists. But I believe this will introduce other problems. For example, one thread might have a lot of work pending, while another thread might have no work pending. In essence, I believe that a solution which assigns work to a particular thread **in advance** might become very complex and and is sub-optimal.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this would have any significant performance impact. Also, why don't you use a standard ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: I forgot to mention: my target JVM is 1.4. Hence, I am writing a solution myself.

Comment: Then I would use a more recent VM. That would probably have a better impact on performance. 1.4 is extremely old. It's not even supported anymore. BTW, the best practice is to call notifyAll(), which would make unneeded wakeups much more frequent. But it's still a best practice. It probably wouldn't be if it had a significant impact on performance.

Comment: I am tied to 1.4 :(. I understand your remark about notify versus notifyAll, but I believe this is a perfect example to use notify instead of notifyAll. There is no reason to wake up 12 threads (as in my example) for only one work action.

Comment: When you are tied to Java 1.4, you can use the backport of [java.util.concurrent](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|backport-util-concurrent|backport-util-concurrent|3.1|jar).

Comment: I agree with that. But I think it wouldn't be a best practice to call notifyAll if waking up threads for nothing had a dramatic impact on performance. It probably doesn't have any significant impact.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is a thread pooling. Take a look at pre java-5 concurrency framework, PooledExecutor class there:
http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html

Comment: I know about the PooledExecutor, but I cannot use it in my example. My question was heavily generalized. In my instance, not all threads are allowed to run in parallel at each time, to give an example. I also asked the question out of curiosity. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my previous answer - another solution. This question makes me curious.

Here, I added a check with volatile boolean.

It does not completely avoid the situation of uselessly wakening up a thread but helps to avoid it. Actually, I do not see how this could be completely avoided without additional restrictions like "we know that after 100ms a job will most likely be done".

```
volatile boolean free = false;

while (true) {
    synchronized (work) {
        free = false;               // new rev.2
        while (work.isEmpty()) {
            work.wait();
        }
        r = work.removeFirst();
    }
    r.execute();
    free = true;        // new
}
```

--

```
synchronized (work) {
    work.add(r);
    if (!free) {         // new
         work.notify();
    }                    // new
    free = false;        // new rev.2
}
```

Comment: The boolean should probably some kind of atomic integer, since there is more than one thread changing it. I like the idea though.

Comment: There are no atomic integers in java-1.4. Thus, read-and-set will not be not atomic.

Comment: True. I'll try to benchmark the difference. I think the "free = true" in thread A will be undone by the "free = false" in thread B in a lot if cases.

Comment: Yes, the best thing is to try it. Perhaps if tasks a short enough then uselessly wakening rate will be lower. I changed the code to be likely safer, see edit history and "rev.2" markers.